# Asterisk trunk private network, remote ext. has no sound

Tags: networking, audio, asterisk

I'm having issues with sound when it comes to remote extensions. If a local and remote extension try to talk there is no sound.

The issue is that the trunk is on a private network.

If 
externip=10.190.10.40

is set to the private network IP everything besides the remote extensions work, since the remote connection is trying to connect sip:1@10.190.10.40 and ofc can't access it. If I VPN it works

If I put in my static public IP from the Router, the remote extensions can talk. But then whenever an outside call calls into my system I can't hear them. They can hear me though

It's setup like this:

TRUNK ----private network----eth1(10.188.0.0/255.252.0.0)

Internet----router----eth0(192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0)

Now I'm guessing I would have to make a route that when I call from a remote extension would go from eth0 to 10.190.10.40. Although I'm really not sure how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

There are no any issues with such setup.

If you trunk in local network, you have it into localnet= section and disable nat on it.

Asterisk will nto show external ip to internal networks described via localnet

Comment: localnet=192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
localnet=10.188.0.0/255.252.0.0

I had it setup like this and doesn't work

Comment: localnet=10.190.10.40/32 and nat=no on trunk